# Python / JSON sorting array by a certain key

Tags: python, arrays, json, sorting

From the result of my JSON I got this:

```
{

   "792777": {

      "parent_area": null,

      "generation_high": 7,

      "all_names": {},

      "id": 792777,

      "codes": {

         "osm_rel": "59470"

      },

      "name": "Brasil",

      "country": "G",

      "type_name": "OSM Administrative Boundary Level 2",

      "generation_low": 7,

      "country_name": "Global",

      "type": "O02"

   },

   "792876": {

      "parent_area": null,

      "generation_high": 7,

      "all_names": {},

      "id": 792876,

      "codes": {

         "osm_rel": "3073228"

      },

      "name": "Região Sudeste",

      "country": "G",

      "type_name": "OSM Administrative Boundary Level 3",

      "generation_low": 7,

      "country_name": "Global",

      "type": "O03"

   },
}
```

Then, with this JSON I do this:

```
    for area in sorted(data.keys()):
        print data[area]["type"]
```

My problem is that I have to sort my dict by the "type" attribute of my JSON.

**Important:** Attribute "type" has string and int concatenated, "O02" and "O03"..

I tried this:

```
    for area in sorted(data.keys(), keys="type"):
        print data[area]["type"]
```

Didn't work! Any help will be aprreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your are misunderstanding the usage of `key` argument of sorted. From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted):

> key specifies a function of one argument that is used to extract a comparison key from each list element

Therefore, it **must be a function**, that takes a single item from your iterable to sort, a single area like `"792876"` in this case, and returns a comparable key.

```
data = json.loads(...)

def get_type_by_area(areax):
    return data[areax]["type"]

for area in sorted(data, key=get_type_by_area):
    pass  # Do something
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind. You can't sort dictionaries. It is because how they work.
However, Python provides collections.OrderedDict that you can use to keep data in order as it was added.

```
a = OrderedDict()
for k in sorted(data.keys()):
    a[k] = data[k]
```